# Customizing QGIS for vehicle tracking

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gps

I'm doing a project on vehicle tracking using GIS - for that I'm using the open source software package [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/).

How do I customise QGIS using the Python console to edit the point shapefile geometries?

I want the point file to get updated as the location of the vehicle changes.

Answer (score 5):

QGIS already has a [GPS tracker tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/live_GPS_tracking.html). There is no need to develop something from scratch.

[image: GPS tracker in QGIS]